# Azure Powershell VM Stopped status in variable

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will look for shutdown VMs in my Resource Group and deallocate them. The output of the below script does not give me the VM name "clean" when I attempt tp assign the below as a variable. The end result is to execute the Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName LAB -Name $VM -force

So for more context, lets say AVGJOE-DC1 is in a stopped state and I run the below line in Azure Powershell it will display

```
Name
----
AVGJOE-DC1
```

If I then if I tried to use $VM to call AVGJOE-DC1 in the

```
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName LAB -Name $VM -force
```

it fails due to the variable being set to a longer string something like 
`MicroSoftComputerResource\Resourcegroup[@Name=AVGJOE-DC1]`.
Hopefully that makes sense.

```
  $VM = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName LAB | get-azurermvm -Status | ?{$_.statuses.displaystatus -eq "VM stopped"} | select name
```

Comment: Can you clarify, and give examples of what you mean that it doesn't give you the VM name "clean"?

Comment: Added a little more context hopefully that helps.

Comment: `select name` gives you an **object** with property `name`. If you want the string VALUE of that property, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Theo said in the comment, `select name` gives you an object with property `name`. If you want the string `value` of the name property, you can use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty name` instead of `select name`.

[image]